# Uploadify is not passing through the scriptData parameters

Tags: jquery, file-upload, uploadify

I'm using the [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com) script on my site and I'm trying to set the `scriptData` parameter based on some form fields.  This is the HTML/JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function UploadFile() {
        $('#file_upload').uploadifySettings({
            scriptData: $('#uploadForm').serializeObject()
        });

        $('#file_upload').uploadifyUpload();
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#file_upload').uploadify({
            'uploader': '/Scripts/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
            'script': '/File/Upload',
            'cancelImg': '/Scripts/uploadify/cancel.png',
            'folder': '/uploads',
            'fileExt': '*.doc, *.pdf',
            'buttonText': 'Select File',
            'auto': false,
            'onSelect': function (event, ID, fileObj) {
                $('#uploadForm #FileName').val(fileObj.name);           
            }
        });
    });
</script>
<form id="uploadForm">
<div><label for="Description">Description</label> <input id="Description" name="Description" type="text" value="" /></div>
<div><label for="FileName">File Name</label> <input id="FileName" name="FileName" type="text" value="" /></div>    <input id="file_upload" name="file_upload" type="file" />
<button onclick="UploadFile();" type="button">Upload</button>
</form>
```

`serializeObject` is just using the [serializeobject](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ba-jquery-serializeobject-plugin) jQuery plugin to turn the form values into a json object

It uploads the file fine, but nothing in `scriptData` gets sent.  I've checked in fiddler & the only form values are the ones from the uploadify script: `folder`, `fileext`, `Filedata` & `Upload`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aaargh, so I just didn't [read the doco properly](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/methods/uploadifysettings/), I was doing this to set the `scriptData`:

```
$('#file_upload').uploadifySettings({
    scriptData: $('#uploadForm').serializeObject()
});
```

When what I needed to be doing was

```
$('#file_upload').uploadifySettings('scriptData', $('#uploadForm').serializeObject());
```

It now works

Comment: The thing I ran into was trying to set `scriptData` in the `$(x).uploadify()` call. I couldn't make it work even though TFM says it should.

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same problem. My solution was to add an [`onSelectOnce`](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/events/onselectonce/) handler that build the appropriate [`scriptData`](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/options/scriptdata/) object and then called [`uploadifySettings`](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/methods/uploadifysettings/) to attach it. Something like this should work in your case:

```
onSelectOnce: function() {
    var data = $('#uploadForm').serializeObject();
    $('#file_upload').uploadifySettings('scriptData', data);
    return true;
}
```

A bit of a kludge but it got it working for me.

Comment: Sadly that didn't help, also I can't guarantee when the users will select the file in the form so they may edit form fields after selecting the file

Answer (score 0):

I wear this:

```
 'formData' : {
 'data'      : 'Hello Word',
 'timestamp' : '2020-05-30 16:06:30',
 'token'     : '59284aa85709ddaf3bd246030060f6a2'
},
```